# Maximum character length in Well Known Text for QGIS

Tags: qgis, well-known-text

Is there a maximum limit of characters in an Well Known Text (WKT) that allowed by QGIS Desktop?

Comment: I **guess** not, since there is no limit to the number of vertices a feature may have (as far as I know).

Comment: It might depend on where you are using the WKT, checking the source code is probably the only certain way to find out

Comment: If you try to write the WKT in a text field, you will be limited by the text field size ( and the maximun may depend on the data storage format), to get meaningful answer you should tell us more on how you want to use WKT

Comment: It might depend on file format? A .csv is limited to 50MB, a .txt to 500MB etc

Comment: @Andrew Tice Yes but a shapefile has a 255 characters limits for text field for exemple...

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried with hundered thousand characters in one line and it worked.

Comment: @J.R WKT don't have to be in shapefile format https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry

Answer (score 2):

I tried with hundred thousand characters in one line and it worked.